# Why does it have a Java generics compile error?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, wildcard

The strong and emphasis line got a compile error:
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) L exist so that Collection conforms to List

```
CollectionRela.init(MaterialAidUnitDto::getAidUnitId, MaterialAidUnitDto::getAidName, new Function<List<Long>, List<MaterialAidUnitDto>>() {
            @Override
            public List<MaterialAidUnitDto> apply(List<Long> longs) {
                return udcService.queryMaterialUnitByIds(longs);
            }
        });

        final Function<List<Long>, List<MaterialAidUnitDto>> queryMaterialUnitByIds = udcService::queryMaterialUnitByIds;

        CollectionRela.init(MaterialAidUnitDto::getAidUnitId, MaterialAidUnitDto::getAidName, queryMaterialUnitByIds);
        ***CollectionRela.init(MaterialAidUnitDto::getAidUnitId, MaterialAidUnitDto::getAidName, udcService::queryMaterialUnitByIds);***
```

[image: code with compile error]

this is the method defination:

```
 public static <C extends Collection<T>, L, R, T> CollectionRela<C, L, R, T> init(Function<T, L> left, Function<T, R> right,
            Function<? Extends Collection<L>, C> supplier) {
        CollectionRela<C, L, R, T> collectionRela = new CollectionRela<C, L, R, T>(left, right, supplier);
        return collectionRela;
    }
```

Why does it have a compile error?

Comment: What is return type of `getAidUnitId()`?

Comment: Function<MaterialAidUnitDto, Long> getAidUnitId = MaterialAidUnitDto::getAidUnitId;
It is Long

Comment: What is signature of `queryMaterialUnitByIds(...)`?

Comment: The signature  is : List<MaterialAidUnitDto> queryMaterialUnitByIds(List<Long> materialUnitIds);

Comment: I noticed you don't have any constraints around your type variables; this could be the cause.